# ModuleNotFoundError when pytest tests are in /tests directory in new project

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I am trying to introduce tests early to a Python 3.9 project, however I am having trouble getting going with pytest.

`test_legacy.py`:

```
from crmpicco.subtasks.legacy import Legacy

def test_is_complete(self):
    legacy = Legacy()
    assert legacy.is_complete(self) == True
```

The class I am trying to test is in `legacy.py`:

```
from crmpicco.subtasks.subtask import Subtask


class Legacy(Subtask):
    def execute(self):
        print("legacy")

    def is_complete(self):
        return True
```

when I run this I get:

> ImportError while importing test module
> '/private/var/www/crmpicco/crmpicco/tests/test_legacy.py'. Hint: make
> sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
>
> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crmpicco'

I have tried adding a `__init__.py` file to my `/tests` directory and then removing it again but it has no effect

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed this for me was adding a `PYTHONPATH` export to my shell.

`export PYTHONPATH=/var/www/crmpicco/crmpicco`

Answer (score 0):

`pytest` [tries to find rootdir](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#finding-the-rootdir) and probably it things it's `/private/var/www/crmpicco/crmpicco`
The simplest way would be run tests with `python -m pytest` which run `pytest` but adds . to `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: I tried that too, but to no avail. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rainmaker'`